# How can I show the CC recipients separately to the To recipients in Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

In both the reading pane and message windows on Outlook 2016, the "To" and "Cc" recipients are collapsed into a single list. Whilst you can use the drop down arrow to show whether an email I've received was directly to me or I'm just a carbon copy recipient, is there any way to always show the To and Cc lists separately without having to drop this down for every email?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the Up/Down arrow in the bottom right corner of mail header area. This button will show full header info.

Comment: I want a solution "without having to drop this down for every email"

Comment: for me: if I drop it down it is dropped down for other emails as well, so the comment of @RowlandShaw of 2017-02-16 may have been solved somewhere the last 2 years (I am using Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus Outlook Version 1803), thus +1

Answer (score 1):

If you make the reading pane larger by clicking the up/down arrow all the way to the right of the window, it will expand the To and Cc lines into 2 separate lines

Answer (score 1):

Change the view to 'Preview' by navigating to the View tab -> Current View -> Change View -> then select 'Preview'. By default, the reading pane is hidden in this view, so you'll need to turn it back on by navigating to the View tab -> Layout -> Reading Pane -> then selecting 'Right' or 'Bottom'.